# Joining sharepoint 2007 lists in a web view based on a common key field

Tags: sharepoint, dataview

So - I'm making a data view that is to contain a list.  This list has a field that will be used to match up against two other lists.  If there is an entry for this value, it should show the value from the other list, otherwise show a link to add a new one.

So, what I need to do is make a data source consisting of the rows from list 1, and fill in the Ticket field with a value from the Tickets table matching the ID value from list 1.  The same should be done for the Change Type field.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?  I've found a few tutorials, but they seem to be for showing all the data together and not match up on any specific columns for linkage.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are aiming at is not available in SharePoint out of the box.

There are two approaches you can look at:

> 1. Create your own custom lookup field template for single/multiple field
>      selection with some sort of field
>      editor. Create your own controls and
>      program the associated code behind
>      logic.
> 2. Use some existing custom solutions. One such sample is on codeplex:

[SharePoint Filtered Lookup Field](http://filteredlookup.codeplex.com/)